# Creating a table in SQL, and taking advantage of metadata

Tags: sql, oracle, metadata, create-table

To homework, asking me to make a table of a DB, the table corresponds to a branch of a department store, this table must contain the following information:

```
CREATE TABLE STORE
(

id_store varchar (50),
name_store varchar (50),
city varchar (50),
country varchar (50),
region varchar (50)
);
```

My question is do we need to have the fields of city, country and region, or by the metadata information I can set a pattern for which that information is provided by the decomposition of the primary key id_state? For example the first 3 digits correspond to the country and the next 3 correspond to the city and so on.

Comment: You have practical problems. All your columns are NULLable so you cannot have a key by definition. The first three letters of country name will not yield a unique key (ditto other columns, proabably); consider instead using the ISO 3166 Alpha-3 codes (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3). All your columns are 50 characters wide which is a 'smell'...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would never want to create a system where the primary key tries to encode data about other attributes in the row.  That is the path to great heartache and much suffering.

- It makes updates terribly difficult.  If you decide that Mexico belongs with the Central American region rather than the North American region, for example, you would have to go through and update all the primary keys for your Mexican stores along with every place in the system that those primary keys are referenced.  That is a tremendous amount of work, it is incredibly unlikely to actually get done, and it is a very costly operation in terms of runtime and testing.
- It makes querying the data much more complicated.  Now if you want to find all the stores in Mexico, you have to write code that makes multiple calls to `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` to parse out which country a row is in.  That is eminently more difficult to index and for the optimizer to understand than a separate column.  It's also much harder to ensure that you don't have 'MEX', 'mex', and 'mx' rows all representing Mexico.
- And it violates general principles of normalization.  City, country, and region are separate identifiable attributes of a store.  They should be given a separate column.

Comment: Consider industry standard keys ISBN (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number), EAN (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number_(EAN)) have *eliminated* great heartache and much suffering by "encoding data about other attributes". The difference of course is that these identifiers have agencies to act as trusted sources. An individual enterprise could establish a similar trusted source if they wanted to produce such 'intelligent' keys for their own use but perhaps not in the same way the OP is proposing.

Comment: @onedaywhen - I wouldn't use ISBN as a primary key-- they've already gone from 10 to 13-digit ISBN's, so most items have both.  These sorts of keys (ISBN's, bar codes, etc.) are great if you're trying to do something like scan a physical item, get one attribute, and to do a database lookup to get a bunch of other information.  They're less than ideal if you're trying to build a data model.  You'd still have all the information that the ISBN encodes in separate columns in the database.